# Mock requests.json after getting response in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest.mock

I have test:

```
class MyTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.myclient = MyClient()

    @mock.patch('the_file.requests.json')
    def test_myfunc(self, mock_item):
        mock_item.return_value = [
                    {'itemId': 1},
                    {'itemId': 2},
        ]
        item_ids = self.myclient.get_item_ids()
        self.assertEqual(item_ids, [1, 2])
```

in the file I have

```
import requests

class MyClient(object):

    def get_product_info(self):
            response = requests.get(PRODUCT_INFO_URL)
            return response.json()
```

My goal is to mock `get_product_info()` to return the `return_value` data in the test. I have tried mocking `requests.json` and `requests.get.json`, both error out on no attribute, I've mocked `the_file.MyClient.get_product_info` which doesn't cause error but doesn't work, it returns the real data.

How can I mock this `get_product_info` which uses requests library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just patch `get_product_info()`.

```
from unittest.mock import patch


class MyClient(object):
    def get_product_info(self):
        return 'x'

with patch('__main__.MyClient.get_product_info', return_value='z'):
    client = MyClient()
    info = client.get_product_info()
    print('Info is {}'.format(info))
    # >> Info is z
```

Just switch `__main__` to the name of your module. You might also find [`patch.object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object) useful.